# How to install yarn on docker FROM node:9.11.2-alpine?

Tags: docker, yarnpkg

my docker

```
 - FROM node:9.11.2-alpine
 - RUN apk add yarn
```

And error:

```
yarn (missing):    required by: world[yarn]
[91mWARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.84815163.tar.gz: No such file or directory
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.24d64ab1.tar.gz: No such file or directory
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add yarn' returned a non-zero code: 1

[Sat Jun 23 2018 16:04:57 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] ERROR Child process exited with code 1
```

I can't understand why is so hard to add Yarn to a docker. I tried so many things and all fails in some ways or another.

Until yesterday I was able to install Yarn on my docker with `RUN npm install -g yarn` but this morning stopped working with error:

> request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

Some of the things I've tried:

- No results for "inurl:yarnpkg.com docker" in google
- https://github.com/mhart/alpine-node/issues/65

**Edit one day after:**

Now when I do `yarn install` I'm getting `getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.yarnpkg.com:443` errors on every package.

looks like restarting docker fixes it. Also more info at https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/

Answer (score 14):

```
RUN set -eux \
    & apk add \
        --no-cache \
        nodejs \
        yarn
```

Comment: This worked most reliably for me, both for `docker` and `docker-compose`.

Answer (score 9):

The latest `yarn` package is only available in the edge repository. This means, you should install it as follows (including the latest `nodejs` version):

```
RUN apk --no-cache add nodejs yarn --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
```

Answer (score 8):

As dumb as it sounds, looks like `yarn` is already installed in this docker version of node. So there is no need to install `yarn` at all.

Anyway not sure why `RUN npm install -g yarn` stopped working from one day to another.

Comment: Well if you happen to need to install something, the solution would be to first call `apk update` to fetch the package index, then `apk add yarn` would work as expected.